# What is standard encoding for ServiceConfiguration.cscfg file in Windows Azure?

Tags: azure

What is standard encoding for ServiceConfiguration.cscfg file in Windows Azure ?
And how to put symbols like --> **©** in that file.(Setting name="CopyrightsSymbol" value="©") ?

Comment: Isn't that an XML file? If so then the encoding is UTF-8, unless the header states something else.

Comment: Also: if your subject is exactly the same as your body, then you're probably doing something wrong. Either your subject is too long and detailed or your body is too short and misses details. Or both.

Answer (score 2):

```
Setting name="CopyrightsSymbol" value="&copy;"
```

rendered in a page: ©

Comment: I tried &copy; but it could not work on app deployed on Windows Azure. It works well on dev fabric.

Comment: @Nicholas, I edited your post to add some formatting that removed the need to include the spaces after &